# Can't align <div> tags

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

I have several issues with aligning my `<div>` tags, as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yotamoo/cr8s8/).
The layout is as so: I have a container header, and inside of it I have a header, a footer and in between them two right and left divs. My problem is with the right and the footer where things aren't aligned to the center even though they are suppose to inherit it from the `<body>` tag.

Also, for some reason the page can be scrolled to the right a little, and in that little part the background isn't colored.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Rock-paper-scissers</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="rps.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    width: 100%;
    font: 100.01% "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#93e1d1), to(#d4c87c));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #93e1d1, #d4c87c); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93e1d1, #d4c87c);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div#footer {
    width: 100%;
}
div#container {
    text-align: center;
}
div.InnerLeft {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
div.InnerRight {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 220px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 0px;
    height: 34px;
}
img#andale {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<img src="header.png">
<div class="InnerLeft">
<img src="uno.png"><br>
<select id="p1" onchange="change('p1','rpsleft')">
<option value=0>Choose your weapon</option>
<option value=1>Rock</option>
<option value=2>Paper</option>
<option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
<p><img src="rpsL.png" id="rpsleft"></p>
</div>
<div class="InnerRight">
<img src="dos.png"><br>
<select id="p2" style="margin-left:45%;" onchange="change('p2','rpsright')">
<option value=0>Choose your weapon</option>
<option value=1>Rock</option>
<option value=2>Paper</option>
<option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
<p><img src="rps.png" id="rpsright" style="margin-left:45%;"></p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<img src="andale.png" id="andale" onclick="rps(document.getElementById('p1').value,document.getElementById('p2').value)"
onMouseOver="document.getElementById('andale').src='andale2.png'"
onMouseOut="document.getElementById('andale').src='andale.png'">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any ideas how I can solve these two little problems?

Thanks!

P.s. I tired to set the image sources to my dropbox and google drive account so they can be seen on jsFiddle, but it doesn't work. Any suggestion as to which site I can use?

Comment: The `body` section of jsFiddle only gets the contents of your `<body>` tags.  The resources from the header get added by `Add Resources` on the left.  Links to externals including images must be the full URL's including the domain name.  http://jsfiddle.net/cr8s8/22/

Comment: Also, to make your question useful to others, also put the relevant code within the post itself for after the link goes dead.

Comment: A link to dropbox doesn't work. You know something I can use?

Comment: You'll need to Google _"free image hosting"_ and use the direct URL they provide.

Comment: For testing purposes, you could also use placehold.it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a few little things...

(sample: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/cr8s8/29/)

```
<!-- for one, without a specified width and height
     the browser doesn't know how to flow the other elements
     around this object ... I used placehold.it to show you what
     happens if you put in an object with actual dimensions -->
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x50">
```

Without an image of specified dimensions, because the image can't load by the browser, the browser defaults it to a very small image, and the first float wraps in front of it, as float:left demands.

You /could/ wrap those floats in a container, as well, and force that to clear:both so that it avoids floating in front of your header image.

Secondly:

```
    <!-- Your extra space was due to the margin-left you shimmed onto 
         this select tag. If you take it out, the extra horiz
         scrolling goes away -->
    <select id="p2" onchange="change('p2','rpsright')">
```

Remember that objects with margins /inside/ another container /can/ "poke through" the borders of the container. Thus, it was adding its margin to that of its container, and pushed itself through the "wall" of its container, increasing horizontal space needed.